# jQuery resizing animação

Tags: jquery

Olá eu estou a fazer um site com uma pequena animação que é alterada consoante o tamanho
da janela mas existem 2 problemas na barra de nav. Os problemas são:

1. `window > 800`: a animação só é trigered quando quando eu mexo no tamanho da janela.
2. `window < 800`: queria que a animação deixa-se de fazer efeito e que respeita-se só os css (media queries para `window < 800`), mas continua, e o menu não respeita os media queries se o abrirmos depois da `animação > 800` for ativada.

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


     $(window).resize(function () {
              if ($(window).width() > 800) {


        $('#upBar, nav').hover(function(){

            $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
                height: '60px'
            }, 200);

      });


      $('#upBar, nav').mouseleave(function(){

            $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
                height: '45px'
            }, 200);
    }
    else {

    }
    })
})
```

Comment: tinha fechado só a copiar para aqui é que não ficou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resposta

O teu problema actual é que a acção só é anexada ao(s) elemento(s) se determinada condição se verificar, neste caso, a largura do ecrã maior que 800 pixeis.

Além disso, da forma que tens o código actualmente, é necessário a realização de uma "limpeza" de estilos resultantes da animação para que o layout continue a responder às `media queries` e/ou demais estilos no teu CSS.

A minha sugestão é alterares o teu código de forma a que os eventos de `hover` e `mouseleave` estejam sempre anexados aos elementos mas só ser realizada a animação se a condição se verificar: largura do ecrã superior a 800 pixeis.

1. #### Animação rato a entrar no elemento

   Função com o código responsável por realizar a animação quando o rato entra no(s) elemento(s) alvo:

   ```js
   // Animação quando o rato vai para cima
   function mouseEnterAnimation(allowAnimation) {
       if (allowAnimation) {
           $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
               "height" : "60px"
           }, 200);

           $('nav ul li').stop(true).animate({
               "padding-top"    : "20px",
               "padding-bottom" : "20px",
               "height"         : "60px"
           }, 200);

           $('#lang').stop(true).animate({
               "padding-top"    : "23px",
               "padding-bottom" : "23px",
               "height"         : "60px"
           }, 200);

           $('#logo').stop(true).animate({
               "margin-top"  : "15px",
               "margin-left" : "10px"
           }, 200);
       }
   }
   ```
2. #### Animação rato a sair no elemento

   Função com o código responsável por realizar a animação quando o rato sai do(s) elemento(s):

   ```js
   // Animação quando o rato sai de cima
   function mouseLeaveAnimation(allowAnimation) {

       if (allowAnimation) {

           $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
               "height": "45px"
           }, 200, function() {
               $('#upBar, nav ul').removeAttr("style"); // limpeza
           });

           $('nav ul li').stop(true).animate({
               "padding-top"    : "13px",
               "padding-bottom" : "13px",
               "height"         : "45px"
           }, 200);

           $('#lang').stop(true).animate({
               "padding-top"    : "16px",
               "padding-bottom" : "16px",
               "height"         : "45px"
           }, 200);

           $('#logo').stop(true).animate({
               "margin-top"  : "7px",
               "margin-left" : "10px"
           }, 200);
       }
   }
   ```

   Dado importante, adicionei uma limpeza após a realização da animação, pois ficava o resíduo da mesma nos elementos e quebrava a altura do menu quando em telas menores que 800 pixeis.

   O que fiz foi chamar uma função quando a animação termina em `$('#upBar, nav ul')`, onde digo que deve ser removida a tag `style` onde ficaram os estilos resultantes da animação:

   ```js
   $('#upBar, nav ul').removeAttr("style");
   ```
3. #### Inicialização do código e controlo da animação

   Aqui estamos a inicializar o código e a controlar se a animação deve ou não ocorrer:

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function () {

       var $topNav = $('#upBar, nav'),                 // colocar elementos alvo em cache
           allowAnimation = ($(window).width() > 800); // verifica se deve animar

       $topNav.hover(
           function(){  // rato a entrar
               mouseEnterAnimation(allowAnimation);
           },
           function(){  // rato a sair
               mouseLeaveAnimation(allowAnimation);
           }
       );

       $(window).resize(function() {
           allowAnimation = ($(window).width() > 800); // atualiza se deve animar
       });
   });
   ```

   - Em primeiro estamos a colocar os elementos alvo em cache, para evitar que estejamos sempre a localizar os mesmos no DOM;
   - Depois estamos a iniciar a variável que autoriza ou nega a animação com o valor resultante da condição largura de tela maior que 800 pixeis (vamos obter ou `true` ou `false`);
   - Anexamos o evento de rato a entrar e rato a sair ao elemento que colocamos em cache;
   - Se o rato estiver a entrar, chamamos a função `mouseEnterAnimation()` e passamos à mesma o estado da animação contido na variável `allowAnimation`;
   - Se o rato estiver a sair, chamamos a função `mouseLeaveAnimation()` e passamos à mesma o estado da animação contido na variável `allowAnimation`;
   - Por último, sempre que a janela está a ser redimensionada, vamos actualizando a nossa variável de controlo com o resultado da condição.

## Resultado das alterações em cima apresentadas

O teu ficheiro `navBar.js` ficaria assim:

```js
// Animação quando o rato vai para cima
function mouseEnterAnimation(allowAnimation) {
    if (allowAnimation) {
        $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
            "height" : "60px"
        }, 200);

        $('nav ul li').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "20px",
            "padding-bottom" : "20px",
            "height"         : "60px"
        }, 200);

        $('#lang').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "23px",
            "padding-bottom" : "23px",
            "height"         : "60px"
        }, 200);

        $('#logo').stop(true).animate({
            "margin-top"  : "15px",
            "margin-left" : "10px"
        }, 200);
    }
}


// Animação quando o rato sai de cima
function mouseLeaveAnimation(allowAnimation) {

    if (allowAnimation) {

        $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
            "height": "45px"
        }, 200, function() {
            $('#upBar, nav ul').removeAttr("style");
        });

        $('nav ul li').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "13px",
            "padding-bottom" : "13px",
            "height"         : "45px"
        }, 200);

        $('#lang').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "16px",
            "padding-bottom" : "16px",
            "height"         : "45px"
        }, 200);

        $('#logo').stop(true).animate({
            "margin-top"  : "7px",
            "margin-left" : "10px"
        }, 200);
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    var $topNav = $('#upBar, nav'),
        allowAnimation = ($(window).width() > 800);

    $topNav.hover(
        function(){
            mouseEnterAnimation(allowAnimation);
        },
        function() {
            mouseLeaveAnimation(allowAnimation);
        }
    );

    $(window).resize(function() {
        allowAnimation = ($(window).width() > 800);
    });
});
```

---

## Revisão

Eu fiz o download dos ficheiros do site a que te referes na pergunta, e devo alertar para o facto de que tens um *exército* de problemas a resolver se queres que as coisas funcionem como pretendido:

1. Auto-fechar tag `HTML`

   Não é suposto estares a auto-fechar a tag `html`, uma vez que a mesma deve ser fechada no final de toda a markup do documento:

   ```html
   <html lang="en"/>
   ```

   Deveria estar:

   ```html
   <html lang="en">
   ```
2. O menu tem a markup trocada

   No teu menu, tens uma lista que contém links para as várias áreas do web-site, mas a mesma contém a markup trocada onde estás a envolver as `li` em `a` quando deveria ser ao contrário, as `li` a envolver os `a`:

   ```html
   <ul>
     <li id ="lang"><a id ="PT" href="#">PT</a> / <a id ="EN" href="about_us.html">EN</a></li>
     <a href="noticias.html"><li>Notícias</li></a>
     <a href="logistica.html"><li>Logística</li></a>
     <a href="servicos.html"><li>Serviços</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Quem Somos</li></a>
   </ul>
   ```

   Deveria ser:

   ```html
   <ul>
     <li id ="lang">
       <a id ="PT" href="#">PT</a> / <a id ="EN" href="about_us.html">EN</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="noticias.html">Notícias</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="logistica.html">Logística</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">Quem Somos</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
   ```
3. Tens um erro referente ao Stellar.js v0.6.2:

   > TypeError: $.stellar is not a function
   >   file:///home/salustiano/Desktop/w/Intertrafego/quem_somos.html
   >   Line 82

   Erros de JavaScript geralmente interrompem a execução de JavaScript na página, particularmente em navegadores um pouco *duros* com o programador.

   O problema está na tag `script` que inclui o `Stellar.js` cuja mesma está:

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.stellar.js"></script>
   ```

   Mas o ficheiro chama-se `jquery.stellar.js`, repara na palavra *jquery* tudo em letras minúsculas, pelo que ou alteras o nome do ficheiro ou a chamada ao mesmo:

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.js"></script>
   ```
4. A [tag de script](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> pode ser utilizada para conter diversos tipos de `script`, pelo que deve ser indicado qual o tipo presente na mesma uma vez que não existe um valor por defeito e o atributo `type` é obrigatório:

   > This attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript"). Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default value for this attribute.

   Que traduzido:

   > Este atributo especifica a linguagem de script do conteúdo do elemento e substitui a linguagem de script padrão. A linguagem de script é especificada como um tipo de conteúdo (por exemplo, "text/javascript"). Os autores devem fornecer um valor para este atributo. Não há valor padrão para este atributo.

   No teu documento, onde tens:

   ```html
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() { 
       ...
     });
   </script>
   ```

   Deverias ter:

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 
       ...
     });
   </script>
   ```

## Resultado da revisão

Uma versão melhorada do teu ficheiro `quem_somos.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Intertrafego - Quem Somos</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/navBar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/footer.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/stylesAboutUs.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    </head>

    <body data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">

        <div id ="upBar"></div>
        <div id ="middleBar"></div>
        <div id="middleImg"></div>
        <div id="missValBar"></div>

        <div id ="wrapper">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img id="logo" src="imgs/logo.png">
                    </a>
                    <a href="about_us.html">
                        <div id="langMobile">PT<br>&#8595;<br>En</div>
                    </a>
                    <div id ="btnMobile">
                        <img src ="imgs/mobileBtn.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li id ="lang">
                            <a id ="PT" href="#">PT</a> / <a id ="EN" href="about_us.html">EN</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="noticias.html">Notícias</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="logistica.html">Logística</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Quem Somos</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <div id="middleText">
                <h1>3 GERAÇÕES DE SERVIÇOS</h1>
                <p>Fundada em 1967, a Intertráfego atua como agente de transportes e transitários internacionais. Tem como base de clientes algumas das mais prestigiadas empresas do nosso país, com um serviço profissional e personalizado. Possui uma frota própria e capacidade de armazenagem. O crescimento gradual desde o seu nascimento, traduz o sucesso de negócio em 3 gerações.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="namesJobs">
                <div id="pedro"><h1>PEDRO NUNES & TOMÉ ELIAS</h1><h2>MATURIDADE</h2><p>Fundadores<br><br>Experiência de mercado e metodologia.</p></div>
                <div id="joaquim"><h1>JOAQUIM PEDRO</h1><h2>PARCERIAS</h2><p>Experiência e know-how no mercado internacional, participando em congressos e feiras internacionais<br><br>Rede de contactos, agentes, fornecedores e clientes.</p></div>
                <div id="miguel"><h1>MIGUEL NUNES</h1><h2>INOVAÇÃO</h2><p>Novos conceitos e empreendorismo<br><br>Inovação e novas tecnologias.</p></div>
            </div>

            <div id="missValText">
                <div id="mission">
                    <h1>MISSÃO</h1><p>A Intertráfego tem como principal missão crescer em conjunto com os seus parceiros, sempre com alta qualidade de serviço e flexibilidade na resolução das necessidades dos seus clientes. Acreditamos que a chave do sucesso está na disponibilidade e empenho que alocamos a cada projecto o que se revela também nas nossas práticas e ambições além fronteiras.</p>
                </div>
                <div id ="val">
                    <h1>VALORES</h1><p>A identidade da Intertráfego é moldada pelos seus clientes e serviços. Quatro valores fundamentais unem a empresa e formam a base da cultura de sucesso empresarial da mesma: Segurança, Inovação, Fiabilidade e Flexibilidade. Os valores assentam na herança das suas gerações e são fonte de inspiração para o futuro.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id ="contact">
                <div id="mail">
                    <a href="mailto:comercial@intertrafego.com" target="_blank"><p>comercial@intertrafego.com</p></a>
                </div>
                <div id="tele">
                    <a href="tel:+(351) 263 470 020"><p>+(351) 263 470 020</p></a>
                </div>
                <a href="pedir_cotacao.html">
                    <div id="cotacao">
                        <p>PEDIR COTAÇÃO</p><img src="imgs/cotArrow.png">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footerTopMargin"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery v1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navBar.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.stellar({
                    horizontalScrolling: false,
                    verticalOffset: 700
                });

                $('li:eq(4)').addClass('active');
                $('#PT').addClass('activeLang');

                $("#btnMobile").on("click", function(){
                    $("nav ul").stop(true).slideToggle();
                });

                $( window ).resize(function navOff() {
                    if ($(window).width() > 800) {
                        $('nav ul').show();
                    } else {
                        $('nav ul').hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Nota:** Existem outras coisas que podiam ser melhoradas, mas realcei apenas o mais problemático.

Comment: Muito obrigado Zuul, perfeito funcionamento. És muito bom nisto. obgado pelas dicas

Answer (score 0):

O código está adicionando eventos aos elementos quando a window > 800

Só que depois quando a janela fica menor, os eventos ainda estao la, pois eles nao foram removidos.

.hover() API: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

> "Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements"

Uma solução possível é colocar o teste do tamanho da janela dentro de cada função executada quando os eventos são acionados:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#upBar, nav').hover(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 800) {
          $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
              height: '60px'
          }, 200);
        }
    });


    $('#upBar, nav').mouseleave(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 800) {
          $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
              height: '45px'
          }, 200);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Não preciso adicionar um 'else' vazio? esse codigo faz sentido mas não está a acontecer nada. Obgado